# Debugging script Netsuite suitescript in Chrome exception

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, netsuite

So I am trying to add a button to the Sales Order form in netsuite that validates certain fields based on what you entered in previous fields. I am having trouble testing and debugging this in google chrome in netsuite. First, here is my code: I am adding the button that calls this function within the client script record.

```
   function vsoeValidate(){

    var calc = nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_cv_vsoe_calculation');

    calc = nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_cv_renewal_rev_amount') - (nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_cv_vsoe_cola') * nlapiGetFieldValue(1-'custbody_cv_vsoe_partner_disc')) - (nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_cv_vsoe_bts_fees') * (1-nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_cv_vsoe_partner_disc'))) /  
           (nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_cv_vsoe_software_amt') * (1- nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_cv_vsoe_multiyear_disc')));

    nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody_cv_vsoe_calculation', calc);

    var display = nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_cv_vsoe_calculation_disp');
    var bucket = nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_cv_vsoe_bucket');

    if(bucket === 'X'){
        return false;
    }        
    if(calc > (nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_cv_vsoe_bucket.custrecord_cv_vsoe_maintenance_rate') *1.15) || calc < ('custbody_cv_vsoe_bucket.custrecord_cv_vsoe_maintenance_rate'*0.85)){
        display = '<div style="; background-color:red; color:white;font-weight:bold;text-align:center">Out of bounds</div>';
        return true;
    } 
    else{ 
        display = '<div style="; background-color:green; color:white;font-weight:bold;text-align:center">In bounds</div>';
        return true; 
    }

}
```

when I click the button I get the error TypeError undefined is not a function.

I am really not sure where to go from here, is it because the logic inside vsoeValidate is not right or am I using the wrong type of function? Any help would be great thank you!

Update: here is the screenshot of my script record!

[image]

[image]

Comment: do I have to pass something in as a parameter for vsoeValidate()?

Comment: All of your field names have to be in strings. You're referencing them all as variables that do not exist. `nlapiGetFieldValue(custbody_cv_vsoe_calculation)` must instead be `nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_cv_vsoe_calculation')`, note the quotes.

Comment: @egrubaugh360 that makes sense so I changed that yet it still throws the same exception undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the function name as string i.e.

```
form.addButton('custpage_validatevsoe', 'Validate VSOE', 'vsoeValidate');
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you set vsoeValidate as a validateField function. Do you want this function to run when users click the button or when NetSuite's valdiateField event is fired (upon field change, before the value is stored)?

If you want this to run on NetSuite's validateField event, then the function must return `true` or `false`; it cannot return void. Right now in your logic, you have:

```
if (bucket = 'x') {
    return;
}
```

`if (bucket = 'x')` is an assignment operation, not an equality check. This assignment operation will return 'x', which is a truthy value, so your code will enter that if-block. You then return void (`undefined`), so my guess is that NetSuite is trying to do something with the result returned by your function but cannot because it returned undefined.

The validateField function also gets passed a parameter that provides the ID of the field being validated.

You will also want to inject some console logging at various points so you can figure out where your script is failing instead of just trying to guess at reading syntax.

Comment: Thanks!!Wow didn't realize the bucket = 'x' should be === 'x'. As far as the parameter for validateVSOE goes, I am confused and am not sure what to put

Comment: because when I try to put the id of the field being validated 'custbody_cv_vsoe_calculation' it has an error and says syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide us with a screenshot of your Script record setup?

Also since you are using a client side script, you don't need to use the pageInit event for adding a custom button.

There is a 'Buttons' subtab, under the 'Scripts' tab when you create the Script record in NetSuite.  This subtab is next to the 'Libraries' subtab.

There are two columns here, 'Label' and 'Function'.

So in your case, you can just put 'Validate VSOE' in the Label field and vsoeValidate in the Function field.

Please note that if you do it this way, the button will only be shown when you are creating or editing a record.

Comment: uploaded the script record screenshots. I am going to mess with the button creation through the record I had no clue I could do that!!

Comment: So I added a button which came up! yet as the page loads I get the exception referenceerror validateVSOE is not defined. I am imagining this is because I have no parameters? I am not sure what to pass in as a parameter..

Comment: You told it the function was validateVSOE, but the function name is vsoeValidate

Comment: oops that was a typo on my part i do have it in there for the button as vsoeValidate ... so all I have for the script record is that button that will launch vsoeValidate on click, nothing in the other function boxes. when I click the button it tells me now typeerror undefined is not a function and I have no clue what to do

Comment: This part nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_cv_vsoe_bucket.custrecord_cv_vsoe_maintenance_rate') does not look right to me.  The nlapiGetFieldValue expects a field id but 'custbody_cv_vsoe_bucket.custrecord_cv_vsoe_maintenance_rate' does not look like a valid field id. It looks like a join which is not possible using nlapiGetFieldValue.